# Confusion on $\Bbb ZG$ module and $\Bbb ZG$ ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm quite confused about the definition of $\Bbb ZG$ modules and $\Bbb ZG$ rings.

- Is the definition of $\Bbb ZG$ module equivalent to "free $\Bbb Z$-module on $G$"?
- Given $G$, are the underlying set of $\Bbb ZG$ module and $\Bbb ZG$ ring exactly the same?
- Given $G$, are the **addition** operation of $\Bbb ZG$ module and $\Bbb ZG$ ring exactly the same?
- When $G$ is finite, is the below picture(from Dummit and Foote) the definition of $\Bbb ZG$ ring? And is the addition operation defined below also the addition operation of $\Bbb ZG$ module when $G$ is finite?[image]
- Finally, is (iv) in the below picture the standard definition of $\Bbb ZG$ ring when $G$ is infinite? Why does the $x^{-1}$ appear? How to think about it?
  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to clarify matters, in the order you addressed them.

1. **NO**, a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module emphatically does **NOT** mean the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module  $\mathbb{Z}^{(G)}$  defined over set $G$, even when $G$ were endowed with a group structure.
2. To delineate the conceptual approach, one first realises that given **any arbitrary ring** $A$ (whether commutative or not, doesn't matter) and **any arbitrary monoid** $M$ (whether finite or not, finiteness is not a prerequisite), to these two objects a new ring can be associated in a canonical (natural) manner. The associated ring is called **the monoid ring of $M$ over $A$ (equivalently, with coefficients in $A$)**, and denoted by $A[M]$. This construction will of course apply in particular for monoids that are actually groups, and the corresponding object will be correspondingly called **group ring**. The notation is inspired by the traditional notation for polynomial rings, $A[X]$ et al, as these rings are themselves standard examples of monoid rings (over free commutative monoids).
3. For an already given and fixed pair of ring $A$ and monoid $M$, we refer to **modules whose ring of scalars is the monoid ring $A[M]$ as $A[M]$-modules**, in accordance with the general terminology: if $T$ is a module over the ring $A$, then we call it an $A$-module. Therefore, if you are given an $A[M]$-module $T$, the internal addition of $T$ is **NOT** the same as the internal addition of the monoid ring $A[M]$.
4. The quoted paragraph serves indeed as a description of group rings (yet no more, as it does not rigorously define ''formal sums'' with a proper grounding in set-theory, it just gives you a ''feel'' of what the elements look like and how you perform the algebraic operations on them).
   The definition goes explicitly as follows: for given ring $A$ and monoid $M$ consider first the direct product of additive groups $(A, +)_{t \in M}$, namely

$$A^M= \prod_{t \in M} A$$
Then, for arbitrary $u \in A^M$ define the support $\mathrm{Supp}\ u=\{t \in M\ |\ u_t \neq 0_A\}$ and introduce the subset
$$A^{(M)}=\{u \in A^M\ |\ \mathrm{Supp}\ u\ \mathrm{finite} \}$$

which is easily seen to be a subgroup of the direct product $A^M$, namely the **direct sum** of the additive groups $(A, +)_{t \in M}$. At this point you thus already have an internal addition on the set $A^{(M)}$, conferring an abelian group structure.

Furthermore, define the multiplicative operation $\cdot : A^{(M)} \times A^{(M)} \to A^{(M)}$ such that for any $u, v \in A^{(M)}$ and any $t \in M$:

$$(uv)_t=\sum_{r,\ s \in M \\ rs=t} u_rv_s \tag{1}$$

what we would call multiplication by convolution, as **it intertwines the internal multiplication of the ring $A$ with that of the monoid $M$**.

A routine check will establish that this multiplication on $A^{(M)}$ will in conjunction with the addition described above yield a ring structure on $A^{(M)}$. This is the monoid ring, and from this point on you can denote it by $A[M]$, to highlight the fact that you are considering the entire ring structure on it, and not just the additive group direct sum $A^{(M)}$ (nevertheless, as support sets they are one and the same thing, $A[M]=A^{(M)}$, it is merely a matter of what algebraic structure one is focusing on).

5. In the special case you are examining the internal multiplication on a group ring $A[G]$ (so $G$ is assumed to be a group this time, not merely a monoid), fixing elements $u, v \in A[G]$ and $t \in G$, let us refer to definition (1): notice there that in order to obtain the $t$-component of the product $uv$ you must perform a summation over indices which are **ordered pairs of elements $(r,s)$ of $G$, subject to the condition $rs=t$**. As in a group all elements are symmetrizable, this set of ordered pairs - your index set for the summation - **can actually be written more simply as** $\{(r, r^{-1}t)\}_{r \in G}$ (bijectively paramaterized by $r \in G$) or equivalently as $\{(ts^{-1}, s)_{s \in G}$ (bijectively parameterized by $s$).
6. The way to justify the introduction of this convolutive multiplication is to think about how you multiply ordinary one-indeterminate integer polynomials, for instance: in order to obtain the coefficient at degree $n$ for a product $fg$ you have to evaluate

$$\sum_{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n} f_kg_{n-k}$$ (where by $f_k$ I mean the coefficient at degree $k$ in $f$). In other words, you are considering all pairs $(k, l)$ of natural numbers such that $k+l=n$ and for every such pair you are contributing with the term $f_kg_l$ to the sum considered over all such pairs. That is because the one indeterminate polynomial ring $A[X]$ is actually canonically (naturally) isomorphic to the monoid ring $A[\mathbb{N}]$!

Comment: Thanks! Keep reading the answer. A little question I'm thinking about, is $\Bbb ZG=\oplus_{i\in G}\Bbb Z$? (ignoring the operations, just care about the sets itself)

Comment: Yes of course. The support set of $A[M]$ is obtained as the support set of $A^{(M)}=\bigoplus_{t \in M} A$. In general that is how you define the direct sum of a family of modules (over a given ring), $\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} M_i$ containing only those families of **finite support**.